# Wildcard request / location in nginx?

Tags: nginx, request, url-rewriting, wildcard, config

I have a script that increments a global revision number with each deployment of my website. This number is then mapped into the HTML that loads CSS, JavaScript and sprite assets. This is used as a cache-busting strategy.

e.g `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/screen_r123.css" type="text/css" />`

In Apache, I would rewrite these incrementing URLs back to the actual assets like this:

```
RewriteRule ^css/screen_r(.*).css$ /css/screen_min.css [L]
```

**How would I do the same in nginx**? I'm not sure where to place the regex matching logic.

*Note: I don't want to append a query `?r=123` to the end of the URI because it feels incorrect to pass a query to a static asset, plus I'm behind a Varnish proxy that doesn't include queries in its cache hashes*

---

Here is my current nginx conf for my site:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com
  port_in_redirect off;

  root /usr/share/nginx/mydomain.com/public;
  index index.html index.php;

  #set long expiry for assets
  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location / {
    #FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED
    rewrite ^/css/screen_r(.*).css$ /css/screen.css last;

    # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {     
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV "production";
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
  }

  add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
  add_header Cache-Control "public max-age=60";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. Rewrite directives need to be outside of any `location` block.

This works:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  port_in_redirect off;

  rewrite ^/css/screen_r(.*).css$ /css/screen.css last;
  ...
```